# What does = fl mean in a haml view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I've inherited an app that has this haml to pull in an index.html.haml file for the "home" controller.

```
= fl
- if logged_in?
  = render :partial => 'logged_in_home'
- else
  = render :partial => 'marketing_home'
```

The if statement is clear, but what is the = fl doing? I can't find that anywhere in haml documentation or by googling it.

Comment: Doesn't look like anything common, have you looked in the home_helper?

Comment: It could just be a local variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`= fl` is not a built-in haml method. You could try to see if it defined in any of the following places:

- app/controllers/application_controller
- app/helpers/application_helper
- app/helpers/home_helper
- any other app/helpers/*_helper file
- library codes (lib/*)
- plugin / gem codes

Comment: thaks I found it in my application_helper. It was actually a method for the flash notices:

Comment: That's the importance to define easily understanding method & variable names ;D (I think `= flash_notices` will not make you post a question here)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it's a local variable, especially if you are inside a partial.  What happens when you run the page?  What appears above the partials?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what `fl` is in your application as it probably defined by your application or one of the plugins.

But I will tell you the magic trick to figure it out. Its actually very simple:

- Stick a debugger just before it ;)

Just do

```
= require 'ruby-debug';debugger;fl
```

And refresh your page. The server should stop at this line. Use `s` to step inside 'fl' function and you will find out exactly where is it in 99.99% of the cases (*)

- well, there might be cases when it will not help much, when for example a method is defined dynamically w/o properly setting source files and line.